# Code sorting functions as Functional Interfaces to pass them to testing method

Tags: java, function, functional-programming

I have sorting functions like bubbleSort(args) and mergeSort(args). How would I go about making them passable to other method that would test execution times etc.

I was thinking about making Functional interface with single method sort() but mergeSort needs another method merge(). I can just do it manually in main but I wonder if there's a better way to test many sorting functions for example.

So something like this perhaps?:

```
 public static void testSorting(Integer arr[], String name, SortingFunction<Integer> func ){
     long start = System.nanoTime();
     func.sort(arr);
     long stop = System.nanoTime();
     //lots of testing strings some stuff i dont wanna copy paste it in main 
 }

public Interface SortingFunction <T> {
   public /*T*/ sort(); //need just a single function right so merge sort cant be coded here?
}
```

I have something like this:

```
        SortingFunc bubbleSort = new SortingFunc() {
        @Override
        public void sort(int[] arr) {
            int tmp;
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
                for (int i = 1; i < arr.length - j; i++) {
                    if (arr[i - 1] > arr[i]) {
                        tmp = arr[i - 1];
                        arr[i - 1] = arr[i];
                        arr[i] = tmp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    SortingFunc mergeSort = new SortingFunc() {
        @Override
        public void sort(int[] arr) {
            
        }
    }
```

but I have no idea how to code recursion here into that mergeSort function. I tried doing it like this:

```
SortingFunc mergeSort = new SortingFunc() {
        @Override
        public void sort(int[] arr) {
            class Local {
                void mergeSort(int[] a, int n) {
                    //do merge sorting
                }

                new Local().mergeSort();  //compilation error
            }
        }
    };
```

but I get compilation error: java: illegal start of type

### Solved

The formatting was off, I put new in class body. It should be

```
class Local {
                void mergeSort(int[] a, int n) {
                    //do merge sorting
                }
                
            }
            new Local().mergeSort(arr, arr.length);
```

I present to you my main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        SortingFunc bubbleSort = new SortingFunc() {
        @Override
        public void sort(int[] arr) {
           //bubble sort... 
           
        }
    };

    SortingFunc mergeSort = new SortingFunc() {
        @Override
        public void sort(int[] arr) {
            class Local {
                void mergeSort(int[] a, int n) {
                    //merge sort....
                }

            }
            new Local().mergeSort(arr, arr.length);
        }
    };
    

    System.out.println(test(getNonRepeatableRandomArray(1000),bubbleSort));
    
    System.out.println(test(getReversedSortedArray(1000), mergeSort));
```

It works and looks fabulous thanks to your help and should last me for a while for all my future needs. Now next would be to store sorting algorithms as an object perhaps in a file or downloadable from web.

Comment: What is the issue with merge sort?  Java uses (or used) merge sort as a stable sort for many years and it had only a single method `sort()`.

Comment: @markspace i need second argument for recursion though and have no clue how to do it  i could declare anoynomous class inside method probably with fields but that starts to look messy and complicated

Answer (score 1):

Hoo boy. So little code, so much to cover!

### Bad style 1: Postfix array notation.

`Integer arr[]` is a mistake in more ways than one. It's a style mistake; in java we write `Integer[] arr`. `Integer arr[]` is legal, but not recommended; it's also legal to mix spaces and tabs, but don't do that either. 30 years ago java was created to look, syntax-wise, a lot like C, where that is legal and somewhat common. But java isn't C and nothing like it. The gambit worked; a ton of C coders adopted java. But that does mean there are a bunch of ways to write code that are technically legal, but, don't.

### Bad style 2: Integer instead of int

Secondly, `Integer` is the object wrapper. You don't want it. You want `int`. Integer is a **pointer**, and if the underlying integers are all spread out throughout memory, you're mostly measuring the performance of your cache lines. `int[]` guarantees consecutive memory, at least.

### That's not how you time things

Java is *way* too complicated to time like this. Use [JMH](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-performance/jmh.html). You can search the web for why you need this, there are very many reasons. From isolating 'oh, your winamp switched songs' to hotspot normalization.

### Generics abuse

Generics link things. You use your `T` in one place, that's (almost) always wrong. Just remove it here.

### Code broken

You have a sort method that takes no arguments in your `SortingFunction` functional interface, but then you pass an array to do, which obviously cannot work.

### Answers

Presumably you want something like this:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface IntSorter {
    void sort(int[] arr);
}
```

and define the sorting function that it sorts 'in-place' (that it modifies the `arr`), which means your framework code needs to create a new arr every time, or overwrite every elem in that int array back to the original state which is probably more 'fair' (better odds that memory location issues won't affect your timing).